# How can I call a stored procedure in Google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to save data in server side script with google app maker, by using a call to mysql stored procedure.
Can it be done? if yes so how?

Thx

Comment: I think you should be able to achieve this using a calculated model. Haven't tried but its worth a shot. Although, I recommend you to create script on App Maker to mimic the stored procedure.

Comment: Thx @Morfinismo, I'm using calculated model.